# SSH fails to connect

Tags: ssh, fedora-19

I just updated from fedora 17 to fedora 19 using fedup in both my laptop and desktop. Somehow ssh is not working in both my laptop and desktop.

In both cases I ensured the following:

1. Ports defined in `/etc/ssh/sshd.config`
2. SELINUX set to `permissive`
3. Enabled and started ssh by `/sbin/services sshd start`
4. Checked ssh status with `systemctl status sshd.service` and it says that `Server listening on :: port 9022`
5. Also added port in semanage

It still doesn' t work (`No route to host`)

**EDIT**

Laptop is on wifi and the cables and connections are fine since I can connect to the internet.

*LAPTOP*

IP: `192.168.21.57`

Routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         192.168.20.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp3s0
192.168.20.0    *               255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 wlp3s0
```

pinging the desktop 192.168.14.110 gives no problems:

```
21 packets transmitted, 21 received, 0% packet loss, time 20027ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.118/21.040/128.028/38.759 ms
```

Desktop to laptop ping also works.

Desktop routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         192.168.14.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 em1
192.168.14.0    *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 em1
```

I couldn't open firewall settings though (both in laptop and desktop): If try I open it from the menu or from commandline (`system-config-firewall`) it says: `ERROR: FirewallD is active, please use firewall-config`

I don't have much idea about how to configure firewall from commandline.

What could be wrong ?

Comment: `No route to host` is not SSH specific. It means that there is no route to the host, so all IP connections will fail. Do not bother with the ssh config, instead look at the network settings of both the laptop, the desktop. Add IPs, netmask, the routing table and possibly the firewall settings to your post. In case of FW weirdness, try using an ICMP echo request (aka ping) or a telnet session. I expect those to fail with the same error. (no route to host).  Lastly: check the cables and confirm that those are properly plugged in. (Or rather, do that first :) )

Comment: Oh i got it. it was a FW problem. Disabled FWDaemon and redefined the ports. Working now. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer and to accept it. That way the question gets marked as solved. (If not it will be bumped to the front page now and then until an answer is given).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it was a problem with the firewall.

I stopped firewall, deleted the port (user defined) and redefined it and ssh is working now.

It seems the firewall got reset during the update.